# How can I select entries from list in random order in python

Tags: python, list

Question is simple. I have a list of say 10 entries, I am running a loop over it. What i want here is getting each entry exactly once but in random order.

What is the best and most pythonic way to do it?

Comment: `random.shuffle()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), it returns random elements preventing duplicates:

```
>>> import random
>>> data = range(10)
>>> print(random.sample(data, len(data)))
[2, 4, 8, 7, 0, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9]
```

The original list remains unchanged.

Comment: Small typo: the `)` after `data` should be at the end of the statement.

Comment: It took me a moment to realize the essential difference between `sample` and `shuffle`, but your comment at the end makes it clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

```
In [1]: import random

In [3]: a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [4]: random.shuffle(a)

In [5]: a
Out[5]: [3, 6, 9, 1, 8, 0, 4, 7, 5, 2]
```

Comment: Does not work with python 3 since `range` is an iterator. Apart from that, fine.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the comment! Corrected.

Comment: nice and portable way to correct it :) I was just telling that so you don't get downvotes from the mysterious downvoter here because it didn't work! Anyway, shuffling a range can be an operational case.

Comment: Please explain if `a` is the data or the  indices.

Comment: @OhadEytan It's the data.

Comment: @OhadEytan `b = a[:]`, now perform it on `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the list first by importing the `random` module and using the `shuffle` function:

```
import random
x = ... # A list
random.shuffle(x)
```

Then loop over your list. Note that `shuffle` mutates the original list and does not return the shuffled version.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

original = range(10)
# Make a copy of the original list, as shuffling will be in-place
shuffled = list(original)
random.shuffle(shuffled)
```

Valid remark from Jean-François Fabre: if you were to use the `original` variable and pass it directly to `random.shuffle`, Python would return an error, stating `'range' object does not support item assignment`, as `range` returns a generator.

To solve this, simply replace the assignment with `list(range(10))`.

Comment: what's the difference between upvoted question and this one (apart from the downvoting and the extra hint about the in-place thing)?

Comment: It would be nice (and mature) for whomever is downvoting to explain *why*.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, however small suggestion: in python 3 you NEED to convert range to list because range is a generator (that's the particular case where you use range)

Comment: Spot on, thanks for that. I've updated my answer to include your remark.

Answer (score 0):

You could use shuffle:

```
import random

random.shuffle(yourlist)

# loop as you would normally
for item in yourlist:
.....
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
s=set(range(10))

while len(s)>0:
  s.remove(random.choice(yourlist(s)))
  print(s)
```

Comment: This may return duplicate items.

Comment: you are right, i need to use a set. Didnt test the code..fixing.

Comment: Sets don't support `choice`.